# MapStruct Spring Page to custom object conversion includes check

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mapstruct

I am using MapStruct to convert a `Page` object to a custom object of my application. I am using this mapping in order to convert the content field of the `Page` object to a list of custom objects found in my data model:

`@Mapping(target = "journeys", source = "content")`

While this works OK and does convert the elements when content is present, this does not work correctly in case of no `Page` content. Taking a look at the code seems to show that the following check is added in the generated mapper class:

```java
if ( page.hasContent() ) {
    List<JourneyDateViewResponseDto> list = page.getContent();
    journeyDateViewPageResponseDto.setJourneys( new ArrayList<JourneyDateViewResponseDto>( list ) );
}
```

When this is added the mapping action of the inner objects is omitted, meaning that I end up with a null list. I am not really sure as to why and how this check is added but I would like to find a way of disabling it and simply end up with an empty list of elements. Is there a way this can be done using MapStruct?

Comment: Why not invoke the [Page.map](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Page.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) method, which returns a new Page with the content mapped by a function, instead?

Comment: Sure, I have though of this but there is a pattern in our application where we use MapStruct for those type of operations. On top of that, I would like to know why and how mapstruct adds this check internally. Do note that I am serializing the default `Page` object as well but mapping to a custom object.

Answer (score 0):

MapStruct has the concept of presence checkers (methods that have the pattern `hasXXX`). This is used to decide if a source property needs to be mapped.

In case you want to have a default value in your object I would suggest making sure that your object is instantiated with an empty collection or provide an `@ObjectFactory` for your object in which you are going to set the empty collection.

e.g.

#### Default value in class

```
public class JourneyDateViewPageResponseDto {

    protected List<JourneyDateViewResponseDto> journeys = new ArrayList<>();

    //...

}
```

#### Using `@ObjectFactory`

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {

    JourneyDateViewPageResponseDto map(Page< JourneyDateViewResponseDto> page);

    @ObjectFactory
    default JourneyDateViewPageResponseDto createDto() {
        JourneyDateViewPageResponseDto dto = new JourneyDateViewPageResponseDto();
        dto.setJourneys(new ArrayList<>());
        return dto;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to share an example on how can this be done?

Comment: I've added some examples

Answer (score 0):

```
@Mapping(target = "journeys", source = "content", defaultExpression = "java(java.util.List.of())")
```